# image changed but appears the same in browser

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a php script to crop an image. 
The script overwrites the 'old' image with the 'new' one, but when I reload the page (which is supposed to pickup the new image) I still see the old one.

If i check my hard disk (i'm working on local machine) i can see that the image HAS changed, but the HTML doesn't pick it up. Maybe it's a caching problem? 
How can  I solve it?

thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common technique for ensuring images are never cached is to add the current time in miliseconds to the end of the image's url as a parameter. Your web server will ignore the parameter and serve the same image every time, but your browser (and any intermediate cache) will register a cache miss because the url for the image is different.

```
<a href='/images/someimage.png?d= <?php echo(date("U")); ?> '>
```

Comment: My browser is set to not cash anything, so I was close to crazy... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure your HTML is pointing at the right file; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>?

Comment: yes, pointing to correct file. I've cheched the page source; Also, reloading shows the new image

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a timestamp to the URL. This prevents most browsers from caching the images. Example: http://localhost/test.jpg?1257783872

Edit: Oh, Ryan has already given a similar answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the proper headers to prevent the browser from caching the image?

E.g.: http://www.badpenguin.org/php-howto-control-page-caching

Comment: Some ISPs using squid or other caching proxies flat out ignore that. My back up provider falls into that epoch fail crowd, which is why I still cringe when my primary connection goes out.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but if I'd first check out the most common issues with caching, and only then revert to this kind of ISP practices.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your ISP is using a caching proxy. Check the URL with [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) to see if this is indeed the case. My back-up DSL is from a provider that does this to save bandwidth, its highly annoying. They also ignore every header telling them NOT to do it.